# Unable to start node application since installing PM2

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have installed PM2 to keep my node application running.  (https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

It works great, however...

Since installing and running my app with it

> pm2 start app.js
>   pm2 stop app

I am no longer able to run my app using

> node app.js

Instead I get the following error:

```
domain.js:66
    throw er;
          ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:910:14)
    at listen (net.js:932:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:998:5)
    at Function.app.listen (/home/ssp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:535:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ssp/app.dev.js:22:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

This error usually happens when you try to run the same thing twice.

However app.js is not running.  I have stopped it in PM2.  And when I type

```
ps aux | grep node
```

To check if it is still there, it is not.

Uninstalling PM2 does not seem to fix this.  Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: What does `pm2 list` say? is it still keeping the port open "for convenience"?

Comment: Since pm2 overwrites the process title, your app won't show up using the `ps` command you mention; either grep for `app` (instead of `node`) or use `pm2 list` instead, as Mike suggests.

Comment: Ah, [known issue](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/74)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get this problem do a :

`pm2 kill`

(it kills pm2 and the port is freed)

This bug is really strange and impact only v0.10.x node versions.

I recommend you to use the node v0.11.10

Answer (score 6):

Overall this means that you have a process running on the same port, you can kill it using:

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)
```

just replace 8080 with your server port